# Undefined symbol g_strv_length when installing Mono on Solaris 10 x86

Tags: unix, mono, solaris, gnu-make

I am trying to install Mono on Solaris 10 x86 and I run the following commands before encountering an error:

```
bash-3.00# ./configure --prefix=/usr
bash-3.00# gmake install
.
. (lots of stuff)
.

Making install in test
gmake[2]: Entering directory `/mnt/sf_VMShare/mono-3.2.8/eglib/test'
  CCLD   test-glib
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
g_strv_length                       test_glib-string-util.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to test-glib
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [test-glib] Error 1
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/sf_VMShare/mono-3.2.8/eglib/test'
gmake[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/sf_VMShare/mono-3.2.8/eglib'
gmake: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
bash-3.00#
```

I tried uninstalling everything to do with glib and then installing glib-2.6.2-sol10-intel-local.gz

```
bash-3.00# pkginfo | grep glib
application SMCglib                          glib
```

The version of mono is mono-3.2.8